# Images inside the card not display when i run my project on GitHub page

Tags: javascript, html, es6-promise, service-worker, angular-service-worker

When I run this project page link: https://nayaksofia.github.io/RestaurantReviewTest1/ the images inside the card doesn't display. But, when I run the same project in my local server localhost: 8000, the images are displaying.

Could you please help me to solve this issue.

Here is the link to my project:

https://github.com/nayaksofia/RestaurantReviewTest1

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem in your image path.
Kindly find the below mentioned screenshots
http://prntscr.com/l3ufem --- Originial Path that you are using.

http://prntscr.com/l3ufqb  --- modified Path that displays image.